# .Htaccess RewriteRule redirects all pages to 404 page not found error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a long url in the following format

```
      example.com/user.php?uname=foo&pass=bar
```

the problem with this url is that it is not at all memorable,

So I want to change it into a search engine friendly url

```
  example.com/foo/bar
```

I have tried this rule in my htaccess that is on the web root

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$mysite.com/user.php?uname=$1&pass=$2
```

but the problem is that its not working ,It redirects every page requests to 404 not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a hint you should not be passing passwords through URLs, and in most cases you don't want to pass usernames either. Use POST instead, and save a session ID when people log in.

Comment: no, I am not passing these senstive informations via the url, It is just to show how the structure of my urls is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?uname=$1&pass=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The conditions make sure you don't rewrite any existing file/directories on the server.